# using the loop index value in JS

Tags: javascript

I have the javascript function in my jsp page as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
for(i=0; i<20; i++ ) {
$(".plus"+i).click(function(){
    $(".details"+i).slideToggle(500)
    });
}
});
```

for each iteration i want the output like this:

.plus0
.details0

Next iteration :

.plus1
.details1 and so on. But this is not working. Please help.

Comment: Show your markup also. Is your click not working??? Any error at developer tool's console? I believe you should define variable before using it. Like `var i;`

Comment: There is no error on the console.

Comment: youre not outputting anything in that code. `$(".plus"+i)` is a selector

Comment: "But this is not working" WHAT is not working? What is your actual output?

Comment: Not related to your issue, but you should declare variables, especially counters, e.g. `for (var i=0; …)`.

Answer (score 2):

There will be no error in the console. The issue is that by the time the `click` handler has been triggered, the `for()` loop has already completed, so `i` will always equal `19`.

You can circumvent this behaviour using event data in jQuery. You can update your code as follows:

```
$(function() {
    for( i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) 
    {
        $('.plus' + i).click( { theIndex : i }, function(e) {
            $('.details' + e.data.theIndex).slideToggle(500)
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually, on jsp page i have mulitple plus icon. Some items are hooked with each plus icon. On clicking that plus icon that particular data should be displayed. The data is hooked in details div tag. So on clicking plus0 the corrosponding details 0 should be displayed and so on. For that i have written the js file as given above. I have tried your solution also. But still getting the same issue.

Comment: @user3443612 Without seeing your markup, it's impossible to better answer your question I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused because you are using closures. The reference of i is held by the click event handler. So the latest value of i is seen by all event handlers.

To solve the problem, write a factory function that returns an event handler.

```
var createEventHandler = function (param1) {
    return function (e) {
       $(".plus"+param1).click(function(){
           $(".details"+param1).slideToggle(500)
       });
    } 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    for(i=0; i<20; i++ ) {
       $(".plus"+i).click(createEventHandler(i));
    }
});
```

Read about closure variables.

Comment: There's no need to use a factory function. You can just pass in the value of `i` as event data.

Comment: Actually, on jsp page i have mulitple plus icon. Some items are hooked with each plus icon. On clicking that plus icon that particular data should be displayed. The data is hooked in details div tag. So on clicking plus0 the corrosponding details 0 should be displayed and so on. For that i have written the js file as given above. I have tried your solution also. But still getting the same issue.